# QuerySet.values('field_name') only returns id

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have a model named `Comment` that has another model `Post` as a foreign key. 
It also has a many to many relation with the user model.

```
In [136]: user            = User.get(pk=1)
In [137]: all_comments    = Comment.objects.all()
In [138]: seen_comments   = user.seen_comments.all()
In [139]: unseen_comments = all_comments.difference(seen_comments)
```

Here is the structure of the QuerySets:

```
In [140]: all_comments                                                                                                                                                                                                        
Out[140]: <QuerySet [<Comment: Test comment>, <Comment: Test comment 2>, <Comment: Test comment 3>]>

In [141]: all_comments.values()                                                                                                                                                                                               
Out[141]: <QuerySet [{'id': 17, 'post_id': 44, 'text': 'Test comment', 'created_date': datetime.datetime(2018, 12, 18, 7, 0, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'user_id': 1}, {'id': 19, 'post_id': 44, 'text': 'Test comment 2', 'created_date': datetime.datetime(2018, 12, 19, 9, 0, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'user_id': 20}, {'id': 20, 'post_id': 44, 'text': 'Test comment 3', 'created_date': datetime.datetime(2018, 12, 27, 8, 12, 27, 338467, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'user_id': 1}]>
```

The unseen_comments is a QuerySet of Comment objects.

```
In [142]: unseen_comments                                                                                                                                                                                          
Out[142]: <QuerySet [<Comment: Test comment>, <Comment: Test comment 3>]>

In [143]: unseen_comments.values()                                                                                                                                                                                 
Out[143]: <QuerySet [{'id': 17, 'post_id': 44, 'text': 'Test comment', 'created_date': datetime.datetime(2018, 12, 18, 7, 0, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'user_id': 1}, {'id': 20, 'post_id': 44, 'text': 'Test comment 2', 'created_date': datetime.datetime(2018, 12, 27, 8, 12, 27, 338467, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'user_id': 1}]>
```

Now, if I try to get the id of all posts that are unseen, I get this:

```
In [144]: unseen_comments.values('post_id')                                                                                                                                                                     
Out[144]: <QuerySet [{'post_id': 17}, {'post_id': 20}]>
```

Which is wrong. I expected it to return 44 in both cases.

Likewise, if I try to get the text of each comment I get:

```
In [145]: unseen_comments.values('text')                                                                                                                                                                           
Out[145]: <QuerySet [{'text': 17}, {'text': 20}]>
```

If I do the same thing, but with the original comments QuerySet I get the expected result.

```
In [146]: all_comments.values('post_id')                                                                                                                                                                                   
Out[146]: <QuerySet [{'post_id': 44}, {'post_id': 44}, {'post_id': 44}]>
```

My question is, why doesn't the `unseen_comments.values('post_id')` the expected result?

Comment: Could you please try with `all_comments.values('post__id') `?

Comment: `In [32]: all_comments.values('post__id')`   `Out[32]: <QuerySet [{'post__id': 44}, {'post__id': 44}, {'post__id': 44}]>`
But the issue was never with `all_comments`.